# SSRS Textbox expression filter from Dataset

Tags: reporting-services

Trying to create a TextBox expression:

```
="Validity: " & IIF(Fields!ID.Value = 2, Fields!Value.Value, "") & " from date above."
```

from a dataset:

```
ID; NAME;                VALUE;
1;  Delivery;            x Factory;
2;  Validity;            30 days;
3;  Pricing Structure;   Subject to...;
```

so that the text box would read "Validity: 30 days from date above" but returns "Validity:  from date above"

The problem is the report only allows me to use aggregate First, max, etc from the dataset producing an incorrect result.

```
"Validity: " & IIF(First(Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet") = 1, First(Fields!Value.Value, ), "") & " from date above."
```

"Validity: x Factory from date above"

Comment: Your expression should work if you were just showing your dataset in a table but I guess you are not... Can you show your report design and expected output. Also, can you confirm that the data you have shown is the actual output from your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset is showing "30 days", do you require the text box to show this or do you require it to be "60 days"?

Meanwhile if you restrict you dataset to one row of data, ie insert a where/having clause such as : HAVING        (ID = 2), then you could use the aggregate sum function in your expression:

="Validity: " & IIF(Sum(Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet1") = 2, Fields!Value.Value, "") & " from date above."

Comment: I have corrected the mistake, it's supposed to read "Validity: 30 days from date above". i have tried your expression but it fails as it returns "" because it only finds 1 not 2 or 3.

Comment: The expression i used was: ="Validity: " & IIF(Sum(Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet1") = 2, Fields!Value.Value, "") & " from date above."

Comment: The query for the dataset i used was the following:SELECT        ID, Name, Value
FROM            Table_2
GROUP BY ID, Name, Value
HAVING        (ID = 2)